# Add to PATH on any UNIX system with something like .bashrc

Tags: bash, shell, unix, path, zsh

I'd like for my application to add its own `bin` directory to the path in a means that works across all shells (and, indeed, multiple shells) across all UNIXes. Is this possible?

Specifically, the goal to to add `~/.myapp/bin/` a part of the user's path.

Simply appending `export PATH=~/.myapp/bin:$PATH` to `.bashrc` won't work—what about zsh users etc? Also, I'm not sure that this is even reliable across all shell-supported platforms.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect what you're asking is impossible.  There isn't a central location respected by ALL shells.  Many Bourne-style shells (bash, zsh) may or may not read `~/.profile` depending on their default configuration, but csh and tcsh read an entirely different set of files, and don't use the same commands as bash to set variables like `PATH`.

An alternative strategy many applications use is to install themselves somewhere like **/usr/local/*appname*/** or **/opt/*appname*/** then create symlinks in `/usr/local/bin/`.  For example, on my FreeBSD system:

```
> cd /usr/local/bin ; ls -l drush mailq perl5
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  14 Apr 29 12:22 drush -> ../drush/drush
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  32 Apr 28 15:28 mailq -> ../../../usr/local/sbin/sendmail
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  25 Apr 17 01:17 perl5 -> /usr/local/bin/perl5.12.4
```

Anything you can do to capitalize on existing configuration rather than requiring something custom will reduce the likelihood of failure.

Also, for most platforms, there is an "accepted" way of handling things.  If you are installing software into FreeBSD, it should *really* be done through the FreeBSD "ports" system, which has its own rules about where files should go.  Same with MacPorts, Fink, Emerge, etc.  Read up on your target platforms before you do something that steps on toes in their various user communities.

Comment: Concur, with the comment that `.profile` for Bourne-compatible shells is probably the closest thing to the answer to the original question.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, I would avoid doing this. Put either a symlink or an exec script in `~/bin` and notify the user that they must add it to `$PATH` if it isn't already in there.

Comment: I thought of this, but the `~/bin` thing doesn't play out so nicely with some platforms (especially Macs). Also, I'd like to make the installation as "one-step" as possible.

Comment: OS X should be handled completely differently from other *nixes regardless, so that will end up being less of an issue than you think.

Comment: Why should OS X be handled "completely differently from other *nixes"?

Comment: It already does 90% of things differently, in a manner that OS X users expect. When in Rome, do as the Romans.

Answer (score 0):

On my system both bash and zsh source `/etc/profile.env`, it is a file generated by `env-update` from the contents of `/etc/env.d` directory. But it is probably not a good idea to add path like `~/smth` here, this is also distribution-specific (the only reason why shells use it is code

```
if [ -e /etc/profile.env ] ; then
    . /etc/profile.env
fi
```

in both `/etc/profile` and `/etc/zsh/zprofile`).

Answer (score -1):

In Bash, the variable `$PATH` give you all the `bin` and `sbin` folders separate by `:`.

With a little substitution you can have a list of them. On Snow Leopard for example :

```
$ echo ${PATH//:/ }
/opt/local/bin /opt/local/sbin /sw/bin /sw/sbin /usr/bin /bin /usr/sbin /sbin /usr/local/bin /usr/local/git/bin /usr/X11/bin /usr/X11R6/bin
```